# Unable to Place the Order Error with PayPal Express

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, paypal-express

I am hoping someone has seen this error before. I searched and noticed that other people have had a similar issue and posted on job boards to have someone fix it but I can't find a solution.

I am in the USA and using PayPal Payments Pro to take credit card orders and to also use PayPal Express Checkout. My issue is with PayPal Express Checkout.

The customer comes to the site, loads something into the cart, gets to the Checkout page and chooses PayPal Express. The site kicks the person over to PayPal, you log into PayPal and choose your payment option and then you are sent back to the website to choose the shipping options. After choosing the shipping option and clicking on Place Order, I get an error on that page saying "Unable to Place the Order".

However, the transaction appears successfully in my PayPal account and I also get an email from PayPal saying it was successful. The order also appears in the backend of Magento with the customer's information and I am able to ship the order fine.

But the customer is not seeing the success page but instead the error page. I have turned off the cache (both Magento and third party plugins), I deleted all the contents of the var/cache folder but I still have no clue why the error comes up.

The contents of the exception.log inside var/log has:

```
TIME_STAMP_HERE ERR (3):
exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::queueNewOrderEmail(Array
(
)
)' in /server/path/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php:653
Stack trace:
#0 /server/path/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(634): Varien_Object->__call('queueNewOrderEm...', Array)
#1 /server/path/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(634): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail()
#2 /server/path/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->place('TWO_LETTERS_HERE-TWELVE_CHARACTERS...')
#3 /server/path/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->placeOrderAction()
#4 /server/path/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('placeOrder')
#5 /server/path/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 /server/path/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#7 /server/path/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /server/path/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you cleared cache, flushed apc/OPcache (if in use), ran compilation process (if in use), here is a small list of things to check:

1. Check if all 1.9.1 files have been copies over
2. Open `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` and look for
   `queueNewOrderEmail` method
3. If the method does not exist you don't have latest file
4. If the method exists check if some third party module is rewriting
   the class and check your local code pool for override of the given
   class

Source: [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51852/order-confirmation-not-being-sent)

Comment: Hi, that does point me in the right direction. The newer file is being overwritten. Is there an easy way to compare the two files to see what is different? I've never had to work with such a lenghty document before.

Comment: Figured out that I can use Notepad++ to compare the two files.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue. The database was missing two tables:"core_email_queue" and "core_email_queue_recipients" per the suggestion of this link [Reinstalling PayPal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53531/reinstalling-paypal/53620#53620) and from what I saw in my exception log.

So I did an export from my test site for those tables and imported them into the Live site and that fixed the issue.

However, clearing up the original errors was crucial in order to show the actual issue.